# How to pass escape sequences to python's ord() function?

Tags: python, escaping, ord

I am using Python 3.
I am also using the ord() function in my script.
If I type `ord('\xff')` in the console it returns `255`

Is there a way to insert `\xff` (which is stored in a variable) 
into the `ord()` function without getting

```
error:
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found
```

How does `ord('\xff')` work? ord() doesn't read strings? Whats it reading then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you receiving this data from some user input? In this case, what you meant to read as a single character was read literally as a string of size 4.

```
In [1320]: v = input()
\xff

In [1321]: v
Out[1321]: '\\xff'
```

One workaround is to use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
In [1326]: import ast

In [1327]: v = ast.literal_eval('"{}"'.format(v))

In [1329]: ord(v)
Out[1329]: 255
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I meant! I figured ord() wasn't reading it as a single character.